# How to implement just a 'Purchase Order' solution (without Drupal Commerce)?

Tags: 7, views, nodes, entities

Here is the situation: I need create a content type 'Purchase Order' with just few fields: date, product to buy, quantity, price unit, price total, author. The goal is don't need be finding in the future the SKU of products which we bought before, and in the finish of the year see how many papers or PC we bought. We are small group and I don't believe a complete '[Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce)' solution will be necessary, just a content type, with views for some basic reports.

I though make some small content type 'Purchase Order' with a entity reference to the product(s) content type but I stuck in the quantity field (and price). The problem come when I referenced the product, **add a field to that relationship for the quantity**, and later see in a custom view how many times that product was bought (and link the orders). Also, take the price from the related products, multiply by quantity and count the total price.

Some idea for Drupal 7?

Comment: Drupal Commerce is pretty lightweight, you only enable the modules you actually need. Rather than possibly reinventing the wheel, it would be worth spending some time to see if it meets your needs before considering alternatives. At the very least, it already has all the helper functionality, like summing up an order total, built in. You can probably simulate that with other modules that weren't tailor-made for it, but would you bother when it's already there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are 2 possible alternatives (options) for setting up a simple shopping cart without using [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) (as in your question) (or [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart)) modules.

## Option 1: A lightweight e-shop

If you're only looking for a simple and lightweight e-commerce solution, then have a look at the [Light Shop](https://www.drupal.org/project/lightshop) module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> - Session-stored basket.
> - Adding to basket and its subsequent editing/checkout process is done using AJAX. Also it works fine when JavaScript is turned off.
> - Node based shopping. As the product can be assigned to any node type. One or more. With full support Field API features (regarding nodes).
> - Orders history. For each order will be created a separate node.
> - There is no dependence on other modules.
> - Full support for working with anonymous users
> - Integration with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

## Option 2: A simple shopping cart

If you're only looking for a shopping cart, then have a looking at the [Basic Cart](https://www.drupal.org/project/basic_cart) module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> Basic cart is a very simple shopping cart / checkout process for Drupal, that just sends 2 emails after each order. Along with the shopping cart, this module also provides a block where you can view your cart's content. It's ideal for small websites with only a few products or other content types being sold, for example touristic offers.
>
> **Main difference from Ubercart and Commerce:**
>
> The main difference from Ubercart and Commerce is the possibility of choosing the content types that can be added to the cart. It also doesn't bother you with the Product SKU, that can be a pain when you have just a few products.
>
> **Features:**
>
> - The possibility of choosing the content types that can be added to the cart.
> - The possibility of sending, or not, an email to the customer once an order is placed.
> - Custom email messages for both the site administrator and the customer, along with the order details.
> - Order registration and listing in the administration area using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module.
> - Integration with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.
> - A block with the contents of your shopping cart.

Here is a screenshot of it (note the <kbd>Checkout</kbd> button also ...):

[image]

Comment: OhoH!! I love this community!! I didn't knew those modules, thanks you!!
I was thinking solve it without any 'e-commerce' solution, but after analyze many pros/cons I think you are right guys, that will be reinvent the wheel. I started with Commerce (before see your answer) with Commerce Basic Line Item and Inline Entity Form, whatever, Basic Cart module look like fit my needs, so i will give it a try. Thanks to both of you!!